# Реализация простейшего адаптера ListView с JsonObject Volley

Tags: java, android, listview, android-volley

Имеется Json с Volley

```
 @Override
 public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
     // display response
     Log.d("Response", response.toString());
     try {
         JSONArray table_forms = response.getJSONArray("table_forms");
         for (int i = 0; i < table_forms.length(); i++) {
             JSONObject student = table_forms.getJSONObject(i);
             System.out.println(student);

             String id = student.getString("id");
             String login = student.getString("login");
             String email = student.getString("email");
             String password = student.getString("password");
             txt.append(id + " " + login + " " + email +" "+password+" \n");

         }

         txt.append("===\n");
```

Как реализовать такой простейший адаптер, передать `student` в `simple_list_item_1` ?
Не понимаю куда поместить этот кусок и как правильно передать, поэтому пишу с ошибкой, лишь для понимания.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, student);
lvMain.setAdapter(adapter);`
```

Answer (score 0):

надо было сделать такое

```
list.add(student.toString());
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
lvMain.setAdapter(adapter);
```